# Aligning address with body of letter in scrlttr2

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, scrlttr2

In [`scrlttr2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), I wish to align the address with the body of the letter. I tried this:

```
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\oddsidemargin}
```

But it moves the address almost to the left edge of the paper.

How can I achieve the alignment that I desire?

Example:

#### h.lco

```
\ProvidesFile{h.lco}[2012/07/25]

\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\oddsidemargin}

\endinput
```

#### letter.tex

```
\documentclass[h]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Name\\Address\\City}


\opening{Dear Madam or Sir:}

Hello.

\closing{Very truly yours,}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Markus Kohm, the author if KOMAscript, has included a `nowindow`-lco in the samples to his book (see [*Beispiele aus der 4. Auflage des KOMA-Script-Buches*](http://komascript.de/komascriptbuch4examples)). The sources for the file is:

```
% nowindow.lco
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm
% 
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
% 
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Markus Kohm.
% 
% This work consists of this file only.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesFile{nowindow.lco}%
  [2003/01/24 v0.1 unsupported letter-class-option]
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\oddsidemargin}
\@addtoplength{toaddrhpos}{1in}
\KOMAoptions{backaddress=false}
\endinput
```

Copy this source to a text editor and save it as `nowindow.lco` in your tex search path (your `texmf-local`), or to the same directory as your letter. Remember to update the tex file database (run `texhash` or whatever command on your system, for example ‘Refresh FNDB’ from the Settings in MiKTeX.)

A MWE for the use of `nowindow.lco`:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\LoadLetterOption{nowindow}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name of Recipient \\ Address \\ of \\ Recipient}

\opening{Hello}  % eg. Hello

\closing{Kind regards} %eg. Regards

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

*EDIT*: PSH asks why you have to add 1in to the `\toaddrhpos`. This is explained by Markus Kohn in [this reply at Komascript’s home page](http://komascript.de/node/1619#comments).
An approximate translation from German:

> In the end the 1in originate from the history of TeX. TeX does not start in the outer margin of the page, but move one inch to the left and one inch down. Consequently, the \oddsidemargin is one inch less than the margin on the even side pages. To make it easier for the user, the pseudo-lenght is calculated from the real left margin (and from the real top of the page). Therefore, you have to take that one inch into consideration when you are using \oddsidemargin in an pseudo-lenght.

(German natives, feel free to improve the translation.)

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand why it should be necessary to add 1in.

Comment: This is because TeX by design start the left margin one inch (25.4 mm) from the outer margin and one inch (25.4 mm) from the top margin. You have to compensate for that. You will find the explanation at `www.komascript.de` if you read German.

Comment: Thank you again. Yes, I do read German. I'll have a look at Kohn's explanation.

Answer (score 9):

This answer elaborates on Sveinung's.

At `\opening`, [`scrlttr2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) "moves into position" to print the "to address" using `\move@topl` which is defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\move@topl}{%
  \null\hskip -1in%
  \ifodd\value{page}\hskip -\oddsidemargin\else\hskip -\evensidemargin\fi
  \ignorespaces%
}
```

followed by an `\hskip` of size "`\toaddrhpos`". So, setting "`\toaddrhpos`" to be the same as the distance skipped by `\move@topl` (in the opposite direction), voids any horizontal movement. As such, adding

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}
\makeatother
```

should suffice, since the opening usually is on an odd page.

Comment: Thank you both. That does indeed solve the problem. I don't like the hard-coded value of 1in, but I'll use it for want of a cleaner solution.

Comment: @PSH: The `1in` length is hard-coded in the actual document class file `scrlttr2.cls`. That was the author's choice, so there's no way around it.

Comment: @Werner The 1in is hard coded in the TeX engine.